# Valoración de estrellas múltiples en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

tengo problemas al implementar la valoración  múltiple en mi pagina web y he tratado de la siguiente manera

```
<?php
    require("conexionservidorbd.php");
    $mensajeria= "SELECT mensaje, fecha, nom_usuario, id_apunte, califi, total_not FROM usuario, apuntes where id_foro='$idFo';";
    $MNS = pg_query($conexion, $mensajeria);

    while ($dtasfila = pg_fetch_row($MNS)) {
            echo "<div class='box'>";
            echo "<h3>";echo$dtasfila[2]; echo"</h3>";
            echo "<p>";echo$dtasfila[0]; echo"</p>";
            echo "<p>";echo$dtasfila[1]; echo"</p>";

            echo "<hr/>";
            echo "Calificar: <span id='Estrellas'></span> calificacion=";echo$dtasfila[4]; 
            echo "<hr/>";
            ;echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema?

Comment: A lo mejor necesitas poner un espacio entre `echo $dtasfila`.  O a lo mejor quieres esto: `echo "Calificar: <span id='Estrellas'>".$dtasfila[4]</span>";`

Answer (score 0):

Para concatenar una cadena (string) con variables, propiedades de objetos, valores de arrays, etc... se usa el . (punto).

Te pongo un ejemplo para que lo entiendas mejor.

```
$nombre = "Fulanito";
$edad = 16;

echo "Bienvenido" .$nombre. " a mi página web. Veo que aún tienes" .$edad. " años, así que hazle caso a tus padres"
```

Este echo imprimirá:

> Bienvenido Fulanito a mi página web. Veo que aún tienes 16 años, así que hazle caso a tus padres

Como vez, la concatenación la he hecho con . (punto), tanto por delante de la variable, como por detrás.

En tu caso `echo "Calificar: <span id='Estrellas'></span> calificacion=";echo$dtasfila[4];` estás cortando la ejecución de esta línea poniéndole ; (punto y coma) antes de que llegue al valor.

Answer (score -2):

No deberías de poner un "echo" dentro de otro "echo". Pones el primero y si necesitas poner más, concatenas con un (.)
Ejemplo:

```
echo "Calificar:  calificacion=".$dtasfila[4];
```

Comment: Hola jmarrdiaz. Gracias por responder pero una respuesta que es solo codigo no es de mucha calidad. has de explicar donde está el problema de la pregunta y como tu codigo funciona y lo resuelve. Mira [answer] para más info. un saludo